# Conflict library between Jquery and Jquery tools

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the same page I'm using this code javascript :

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/allinone_bannerRotator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

jQuery(function() {

        jQuery('#allinone_bannerRotator_universal').allinone_bannerRotator({
            skin: 'universal',
            width: 666,
            height: 271,
            thumbsWrapperMarginBottom:35,               
            autoHideBottomNav:false,
            showPreviewThumbs:false
        });     


    });

  ....

  <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("ul.tabs").tabs("div.css-panes > div", {effect: 'ajax'});
  });
  </script>
  <ul class="tabs">
   <li><a href="ajax3.htm">page1</a></li>
   <li><a href="ajax4.htm">page2</a></li>
   <li><a href="ajax5.htm">page3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="css-panes">
   <div style="display:block"></div>
  </div>
```

So I get this strange error:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).allinone_bannerRotator is not a function 
showPreviewThumbs:false
```

Maybe they are a problem of conflict of libraries,so I tried some solutions `$(document).ready(function()` or `$.noConflict()` but I get the same error all time,someone have an idea how to resolve this issue...

Please if you don't have a good solution please don't reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var JQ=jQuery.noConflict():
JQ(function() {

        JQ('#allinone_bannerRotator_universal').allinone_bannerRotator({
            skin: 'universal',
            width: 666,
            height: 271,
            thumbsWrapperMarginBottom:35,               
            autoHideBottomNav:false,
            showPreviewThumbs:false
        });     


    });
```

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

I would try using an older version of jQuery (earlier than jquery-2.0.0.min.js).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Tools includes it's own version of jQuery. Include a version of jQuery tools that doesn't include it's own jQuery.  http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/all/jquery.tools.min.js

Make sure you include your other jquery first, followed by jquery tools, and then the rest.

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="nivoslider.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code like this:

```
(function ($) {

// enter all your code here

})(jQuery);
```

This will avoid any jquery conflicts with other libraries.